# Likely mean of a multinomial distribution with dirichlet prior

Tags: bayesian, nonparametric, multinomial-distribution, nonparametric-bayes

I am working to create a Bayesian non-parametric estimate of the mean of a distribution given a distribution of observations. Ultimately I'd like to get to a credibility interval of the likely mean of the distribution given observed data. This particular example is of prices of orders.

Normally I can use simulation to get around having a deep understanding of the math but in this case something interesting is happening: I've noticed the credibility interval for my estimated mean will always be greater than the true mean. This is due to the preponderance of "uninformative" prior data. How do I fix this so that I can have a true credibility interval like I am expecting?

As an example:

Say I have hypotheses that the value of an order can be anywhere between \$1 to \$10. Then some simple python for this set up might be:

```
hypotheses = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
observations = np.array([1,1000,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
sampled_observations = numpy.random.dirichlet(observations)
the_mean = (sampled_observations*hypotheses).sum()
```

In this example the_mean will never be my actual value and my credible interval will never include the true mean. This is a chart of the distribution of 1,500 samples from that code:
[image: Mean samples]

It's easy to see the credibility interval would be something like \$2.02 to \$2.06. Of course the more initial priors I entertain the worse this problem becomes for example what if I chose \$100 as my largest bucket and assigned priors in the same way? Is there a method for discounting the effect of my prior data or a better prior to choose?

Background: In my real problem I've chosen to bin every penny between \$0 and \$10 and have an average price in my test data around \$2. Which means I have hundreds of bins of very small size that are skewing my data and causing a very poor estimate.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Discrete events are constructed as {0,1} random variables, and so taking the mean of them doesn't quite work like this. That is, the event space here is not as you believe you have designed it.. it is not {\$1, \$2, etc.}. You should consider a continuous event space. You can even use a uniform (improper) prior if the situation allows for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt. Can you point me to any further information on the topic or provide more detail around where this breaks down? I'm pretty sure a continuous event space won't work for me because my data distribution doesn't at all follow a standard probability distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a discrete variable $x$ with $n$ possible values whose distribution you are trying to model as:
$$
\mathbf{\theta} \sim \mathrm{Dirichlet}(\alpha,...,\alpha)
\\
p(x=c_i) = \theta_i
$$
The mean of this distribution is $m = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \theta_i$.  The issue you are seeing is due to the Dirichlet prior on $\theta$ inducing a very strong prior on the mean.  The variance of $m$ under the prior is bounded by:
$$
\mathrm{var}(m) \leq \sum_i c_i^2 \mathrm{var}(\theta_i)
\\
\mathrm{var}(\theta_i) = \frac{1}{n} (1 - \frac{1}{n}) \frac{1}{1 + n\alpha}
$$
For $\alpha=1$, this gives $\mathrm{var}(m) \leq O(n)$ which is too small.  You need $\alpha \approx 1/n$ to get a reasonably large prior variance for $m$.

Comment: I do have prior knowledge about this distribution. Your answer makes me think I may just need a weakly informative prior then to balance things out.